# SecItemAdd creates keychain item with label "octagon-com.apple.security.keychain" instead of provided kSecAttrLabel

Tags: swift, security, cocoa

I use the following code to save a private key with a custom label, but the Keychain app shows an entry with name and account `octagon-com.apple.security.keychain` and type `Octagon Account State (com.apple.security.keychain,defaultContext)`. Can these values be customized, and what is `kSecAttrLabel` if it's not displayed in the Keychain app? The documentation only reads `The corresponding value is of type CFString and contains the user-visible label for this item.`

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        do {
            try storeKey("asdf")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    private func storeKey(_ key: String) throws {
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: key) else {
            fatalError()
        }
        let status = SecItemAdd([kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
                                 kSecAttrLabel as String: "Asdf",
                                 kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: "com.example.app2".data(using: .utf8)!,
                                 kSecAttrKeyClass as String: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
                                 kSecValueData as String: data,
                                 kSecAttrSynchronizable as String: true] as [String: Any] as CFDictionary, nil)

        if status != errSecSuccess {
            throw NSError(domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: Int(status))
        }
    }

}
```